# Python 2.7 built from Source on AIX5.3 does not execute for libpython2.7.so

Tags: python, python-2.7, aix

This is on AIX 5.3.

When i run Python that I built from source, I get the following error (**This is despite the library being present in the path and that path being present in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.**).

```
a776q /app/appadm/.Mim>python2.7/bin/python
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program python2.7/bin/python because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module libpython2.7.so could not be loaded.
        0509-022 Cannot load module libpython2.7.so.
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
a776q /app/appadm/.Mim>export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/app/appadm/.Mim/python2.7/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
a776q /app/appadm/.Mim>python2.7/bin/python
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program python2.7/bin/python because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module libpython2.7.so could not be loaded.
        0509-022 Cannot load module libpython2.7.so.
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
a776q /app/appadm/.Mim>ls -ltr /app/appadm/.Mim/python2.7/lib/
total 5192
-r-xr-xr-x   1 appadm   appadm      2637588 13 ago 07:50 libpython2.7.so
drwxr-sr-x  28 appadm   appadm        14336 13 ago 07:59 python2.7
drwxr-sr-x   2 appadm   appadm          512 13 ago 07:59 pkgconfig
a776q /app/appadm/.Mim>ldd python2.7/bin/python
python2.7/bin/python needs:
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_xpg5.o)
Cannot find      /unix
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
```

I built the python from source using the following

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/vac/bin
export CC=/usr/vac/bin/xlc_r
./configure --with-gcc="xlc_r" --disable-ipv6 AR="ar" --prefix=/app/appadm/.Mim/python2.7 --enable-shared
make
make install
```

Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue was that I was setting **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** when i should instead be setting **LIBPATH** on AIX.